# Aligning elements to the extreme ends

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble aligning elements to the right most and the left most end of the screen. The left part has the logo and the right has an image. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Try css float:left and float:right

Comment: provide some simple code we can look at, Its easier for us to help and better for you to understand.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I recommend all new users visit [ask] for tips about how to write a question that best enables the community to provide useful guidance.  It is customary to provide a [mcve] whenever possible that reproduces the issue-- omitting that greatly limits how much help can be provided.  Good luck, and happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also add below code to the parent element.

```
#parent{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add css below to the left part

```
float: left
display: inline-block
```

and add below css to right part

```
float: right
display: inline-block
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **flex**, If both must be in the same direction.

**First** put the logo and then the image in a container(e.g div).

Then set this css for container:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
```